# Android multipart file upload with OkHttp

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

I am using this for audio records and video file and it is working but i want to replace it with OkHttp. I didnt figure it out. Can anyone help me about it?

```
public class HttpMultipartUpload {
    static String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    static String twoHyphens = "--";
    static String boundary = "AaB03x87yxdkjnxvi7";

    public static String upload(URL url, File file, String fileParameterName, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 20 * 1024;
        try {
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fileParameterName
                    + "\"; filename=\"" + file.toString() + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/xml" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            buffer = new byte[Math.min((int) file.length(), maxBufferSize)];
            int length;
            // read file and write it into form...
            while ((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            for (String name : parameters.keySet()) {
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(parameters.get(name));
            }

            // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            dos.flush();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) fileInputStream.close();
            if (dos != null) dos.close();
        }

        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            return response.toString();
        } finally {
            if (dis != null) dis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change it with OkHttp. Any code please. I dont have good knowledge about on OkHttp. I was using (HttpURLConnection) but it seems not effective now.

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation example on posting form data

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostMultipart.java

```
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("title", "Square Logo")
        .addFormDataPart("image", "logo-square.png",
            RequestBody.create(
                new File("docs/images/logo-square.png"),
                MEDIA_TYPE_PNG))
        .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .header("Authorization", "Client-ID " + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
        .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();
```